# Why is [docker-for-windows] described as only for Hyper-V?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

[docker-for-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows)'s description is "Docker implementation for Windows, **running on Hyper-V**".

Why is limited to just Hyper-V? Even [Docker Desktop on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) **by default** displays the system requirements for the **non** Hyper-V version. Those who want the Hyper-V version actually need to click something extra in order to see the system requirements for the Hyper-V version.

[image: Docker Desktop on Windows' System requirements]

Comment: Just a guess... before WSL2 and associated backends were available Hyper-V was the preferred solution? The tag was [last edited in 2017](https://superuser.com/posts/1188559/revisions) which is quite a while ago. If you have a better tag description, [following our tag wiki guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/tag-excerpts), then you are free to propose it at https://superuser.com/tags/docker-for-windows/info

Comment: Done, thanks, hope it'll get approved.

Comment: Also, the WSL2 backend is built on top of WSL2 which is built on top of the Hyper-V engine, so its arguably not incorrect to say that the WSL2 backend runs on hyper-v as well.

Comment: but one impact of the tech stack to consider, is that you cannot use Docker for Windows on a system where you are already using VirtualBox, since you can't install HyperV and Virtualbox on the same system.

Comment: Isn't that what the WSL2 variant is for?

Comment: Wait a second: "WSL2 backend" would be a Hyper-V backend (WSL2 runs only on Hyper-V) that runs **LINUX** containers. While the "Hyper-V backend and Windows containers" runs **WINDOWS** containers... both choices relate to Hyper-V, one runs Linux via WSL2, the other runs Windows containers. Or am I missing something? So, to answer your questions, "docker-for-windows", according to your screenshot only runs on Hyper-V.

Comment: Since this comment (and also the one about VirtualBox) was remade to an answer, I've commented there.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's only for Hyper-V.

It doesn't work with VirtualBox or anything else. You can choose from Linux containers on WSL2 (which uses Hyper-V) or Windows containers directly on Hyper-V. Either way you have to have Hyper-V enabled.

Comment: [Can I use VirtualBox alongside Docker Desktop? **Yes**, you can run VirtualBox along with Docker Desktop if you have enabled the Windows Hypervisor Platform feature on your machine](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/windowsfaqs/#can-i-use-virtualbox-alongside-docker-desktop). Also, do you have a source for your other claim? It's not mentioned [in here](https://superuser.com/questions/1561465/docker-on-hyper-v-vs-wsl-2).

Comment: @LWC You can use VirtualBox separately, but Docker for Windows requires Hyper-V. It doesn't use VirtualBox. Notice there's no option for VirtualBox in your screenshot.

Comment: @LWC is it mentioned "in here" - "The newest version of WSL uses Hyper-V architecture to enable its virtualization"

Comment: @LWC and according to [this](https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/virtualization/virtualbox-use-virtualbox-and-hyper-v-at-the-same-time.html) then only way that VirtualBox can be used alongside Hyper-V is by VirtualBox switching its backend to use Hyper-V.

Comment: Is there a source for Linux containers having to run on WSL2 (Hyper-V indirectly) while Windows containers having to run on Hyper-V (directly)?

Comment: @LWC your screenshot? Older DfW versions used their own Hyper-V VM for Linux containers with the option for WSL2 instead, but that seems to be discontinued now.